# LINQ query could not translate datetime exception

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting an exception, and I think when it occurs when it tries to execute `y.Duration <= (int)(DateTime.Now - targetDateTime).TotalMinutes` in the LINQ query. Please help me sort this error?

```
string dateString = "2023-06-04 08:34:46.2743289";
DateTime targetDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff", null);

var myUser =  _dbContext.Users
           .Where(u => u.Telephome== telephone)
           .Include(x => x.Activations)
           .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Activations.Any(y =>
                y.Code == code &&
                y.Duration <= (int)(DateTime.Now - targetDateTime).TotalMinutes));
```

I end up having the following exception thrown.

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(u0 => EF.Property<int?>(EntityShaperExpression:
> Xchange.Core.Entities.User
> ValueBufferExpression:
> ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
> IsNullable: False
> , "Id") != null && object.Equals(
> objA: (object)EF.Property<int?>(EntityShaperExpression:
> Xchange.Core.Entities.User
> ValueBufferExpression:
> ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
> IsNullable: False
> , "Id"),
> objB: (object)EF.Property<int?>(u0, "UserId")))
> .Where(u0 => u0.Code == __code_1 && u0.Duration <= (int)(DateTime.Now - u0.TimeStamp).TotalMinutes)' could not be
> translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,
> or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to
> 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Comment: Your LINQ to Entities query has to be translated to SQL to be executed on the database and not all valid C# code can be translated. There is no mapping of that expression to SQL code. You could start reading [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/database-functions).

Answer (score 1):

I've seen something like that. The problem is that the Linq expression has to be translated (e.g. serialized to SQL), but not everything has a counterpart.

However, in your case the solution should be easy, because the critical expression can be (conveniently) calculated in advance:

```
string dateString = "2023-06-04 08:34:46.2743289";
DateTime targetDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff", null);

int duration = (int)((DateTime.Now - targetDateTime).TotalMinutes);

var myUser =  _dbContext.Users
           .Where(u => u.Telephome== telephone)
           .Include(x => x.Activations)
           .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Activations.Any(y =>
                y.Code == code &&
                y.Duration <= duration));
```

Anyway, in your snippet a closing parenthesis is missing (at the very end).

Comment: Ok. What if the `targetDateTime ` is saved as part of a column in the table. How would I calculate if so ?

Comment: good question. I've a little experience on that. However, I'd try to cast the `targetDateTime` and other fields to `double`: if that works, then the calculations are supported for sure.
Anyway, I'd avoid to carry the `DateTime.Now` into the expression. Freeze its value ahead, then use it as a constant.